# What is the max height a keyboard can be in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uikeyboard

Now that iOS8 has introduced custom keyboards, what is the max height that a keyboard can be? Can it potentially take up the whole screen or is there a limit to the height?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I have never made a custom keyboard. I am just asking so I can plan component movement accordingly.

Comment: you should consider it according to the good user experience as may be keyboard size same as the screen size would be no use so that should be at least one line or more smaller than the current view screen size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not limits. I'm tried to create keyboard wich have a height == 1000.0f px. and that has been success.